# TextArea line breaks for e-mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

How can I take the text from a textarea (html) and insert line breaks. Right now, if I input info to send out as an e-mail, it puts all the text on the same line without any line breaks.

Using $_POST['field'] to get the data from the form and sending using PHP mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use \n for new line, or \r\n for return followed by new line

ie.

```
<?php
printf("This is the first line. \n");
printf("This is the second line");
?>
```

ie. to replace 
 html tag with newline:

```
str_replace ('<br>' , '\r\n', $_POST['field'])
```

alternativly set the email you are sending out to be html encoded (add html header)

Answer (score 11):

Use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function. It replaces all newlines within a string with html br tags.

Answer (score 1):

In php, replace \n with html br tag,

```
$newTxt = str_replace("\n",'<br>',$txt)
```

or [nl2br()](http://us.php.net/nl2br) will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

remove `stripslashes()`, this will work.

Comment: [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) removes any instances of `\n` or `\r` but doesn't actually insert an adequate line break into the string as OP requested.